# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'registration' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc

After doing login successfully I need to open registration form that  doing with model view object but is showing error please see the code below. This is my login Controller class:

```
package controller;

import entity.User;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.*;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController {

Service clientService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public LoginController() {
    setCommandClass(User.class);
    setCommandName("user");
    clientService=new ServiceImpl();
}

@Override
protected void doSubmitAction(Object command) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
//Use onSubmit instead of doSubmitAction 
//when you need access to the Request, Response, or BindException objects
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
    User user =(User) command;  
    String UserId = user.getUname();
    String Password = user.getpwd();
    boolean result;

    result=clientService.checkLoginIdPassword(UserId, Password);
    ModelAndView mv=null;
   if(result)
   {      
    System.out.println("Login TRUE");
    mv= new ModelAndView("registrationForm","user",user);
    return mv;
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Login FALSE");
       response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
       return mv;
   }

 }
}
```

My Login.jsp page:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>User Login </title>
     </head>
    <body>
  <h1>User Login</h1>
  <form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
   <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
     <td alignment="right" width="20%">User Id</td>
     <td width="20%"><form:input path="uname"  /></td>
     <td width="60%">
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td alignment="right" width="20%">Password</td>
     <td width="20%"> <form:password path="pwd" /> </td>
     <td width="60%">
  </tr>
  </table>
   <input type="submit" value="login" />
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My registrationForm.jsp page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="registration">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User Name :</td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age :</td>
    <td> <form:input path="age" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gender :</td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="gender" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Country :</td>
    <td>
    <form:input path="country" />
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mobile :</td>
    <td><form:input path="mobile" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email :</td>
    <td>
       <form:input path="email" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>About You</td>
    <td>
    <form:textarea path="aboutYou"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

My DispatcherServlet.xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

 <bean name="/login.htm" class="controller.LoginController"/>
 <bean name="/registrationForm.htm" class="controller.RegistrationController"/>  

<!--view resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
<!--view resolver -->   

</beans>
```

My RegistrationController.java file:

```
package controller;
import entity.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.*;
/** 
 *
 * @author pawan
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class RegistrationController extends SimpleFormController {

Service clientService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public RegistrationController() {

    setCommandClass(Registration.class);
    setCommandName("registration");
    System.out.println(" In Registration----------A--");
    clientService=new ServiceImpl();
}

@Override
protected void doSubmitAction(Object command) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
//Use onSubmit instead of doSubmitAction 
//when you need access to the Request, Response, or BindException objects
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {

  Registration reg=(Registration) command;  

    System.out.println("Name------------"+reg.getName());
    System.out.println("Age-------------"+reg.getage());
    System.out.println("Gender----------"+reg.getGender());
    System.out.println("Mobile----------"+reg.getMobile());
    System.out.println("County----------"+reg.getCountry());
    System.out.println("Email-----------"+reg.getEmail());
    System.out.println("AboutYo---------"+reg.getAboutYou());


    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("home");

   return mv;
   }
}
```

This is the output error I am getting:

```
AAA
BBB
QUERY- SQLQueryImpl(SELECT * FROM user where Username='john' AND Password='rambo')
UserId from DB- John
Password from DB- Rambo
Login TRUE
view name 1 - 
view name 2 - registrationForm
Sep 29, 2014 3:31:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag
SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'registration' available as     request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'registration' available as request attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to appoint a new model in ModelAndView.  if "User" is your model than set mv as

mv= new ModelAndView("registration","user",new User());

And if User is not your model class than put that model instead of user. and don't forgot to add commandName in your spring form tag. here "user" is your commandName.

this will work.

Comment: Hi ....... I have tried by doing this mv=new ModelAndView("registration","user",new User()); But Still it is showing same error.

Comment: Hello I am not able to open another registration page after doing successfully login Can anybody help me ?

Comment: hello, will provide me the exact error you are getting. and instead ModelAndView why you not to try String as return type.